# Custom ListViewAdapter with setOnItemClickListener and Intent

Tags: kotlin, listview, android-intent, adapter, onitemclicklistener

This is the Custom adapter

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Context
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.BaseAdapter
import android.widget.TextView
import com.example.klubbdatabase.R

class ListViewAdapterK(private val activity: Activity, listen: 
ArrayList<String>) : BaseAdapter(){
private var listen = ArrayList<String>()
init {this.listen = listen }
override fun getCount(): Int {return listen.size }
override fun getItem(i: Int): Any {return i}
override fun getItemId(i: Int): Long {return i.toLong()}

@SuppressLint("ViewHolder")
override fun getView(i: Int, convertView: View?, viewGroup: ViewGroup): 
View {
    val vi: View
    val inflater = 
activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as 
LayoutInflater
    vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_kiosker_oppsett, null)
    val oppsett = vi.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.oppsett)
    oppsett.text = listen[i]
    return vi
}
}
```

This is the temporary simle call from main, until I get it to work

```
kioskListe.setOnItemClickListener{ parent, view, position, id ->
        val intent= Intent(this, second::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
```

This is the xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:clickable="true">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/overskrift"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Kiosker"
    android:textSize="100dp"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:textColor="@color/white"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/endreEdit"
    android:layout_below="@id/overskrift"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/edittext_hint"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:inputType="text"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/endreKnapp"
    android:layout_below="@id/endreEdit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:text="Endre navn på kiosk"
    android:textSize="50dp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/listen"
    android:layout_below="@id/endreKnapp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/kioskListe"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        />
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is the xml files for the rows of the listview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:focusable="true"
android:paddingTop="10dp"
android:paddingBottom="10dp"
android:clickable="true"
android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
android:orientation="vertical">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/oppsett"
    android:paddingTop="2dip"
    android:paddingBottom="2dip"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textSize="50dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Everything starts up fine, and I get no errors. I dont get anny errors, but when I click on the list, the row just temporarily gets dark grey. Nothing else happens. What do I need to change to get the setOnItemClickListener work? I can't find anything that has helped me solve this problem, so any kind of help would be much appreciated

Comment: maybe your "second" activity just fails to start?